Is there a way to find out what transport was used after Symfony Mailer sends an email message?
I am trying to find a way to determine which transport was used to send a message after mailer sends a message.
My Symfony config defines 3 transports in config/packages/mailer.yaml:
    mailer:
        transports:
            failover: '%env(FAILOVER_MAILER_DSN)%'
            mailgun: '%env(MAILGUN_MAILER_DSN)%'
            admin: '%env(SMTP_MAILER_DSN)%'

FAILOVER_MAILER_DSN combines the other two DSNs.
I cannot get transport used information from the SentMessageEvent that is dispatched when the message is sent.
If I set an X-Transport header in my message in order to select a transport other than 'failover', I can get the value of that header from the message in a MessageEvent, but if an X-Transport header was not set I cannot tell which of its component transports the failover transport used.

I have found a kludgey answer: get the transport from the MessageEvent that is dispatched immediately before the SentMessageEvent.
class EmailMessageSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    private array $messageTransport = []; 

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            SentMessageEvent::class => 'onSentMessageEvent',
            MessageEvent::class => ['onMessageEvent', -256],
        ];
    }

    public function onMessageEvent(MessageEvent $event): void
    {
        if ($event->isQueued()) {
            return;
        }
        $message = $event->getMessage();
        $this->messageTransport[spl_object_id($message)] = $event->getTransport();
    }

    public function onSentMessageEvent(SentMessageEvent $event): void
    {
        $sentMessage = $event->getMessage();
        $transport = $this->messageTransport[spl_object_id($sentMessage->getOriginalMessage())] ?? null;
        ...
    }
}

